# How to exclude url with ?state... from htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I write a RewriteRule for redirecting

```
www.domain.com/23/title to www.domain.com?index.php?qa=23&qa_1=title
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?qa=$1&qa_1=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Now I want to redirect some url's to special page(everything after ?state) for example :

```
www.domain.com/23/title?state=edit-233 --> www.domain.com/index.php?qa=23&qa_1=title$state=edit-223
```

How can I do it ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to *preserve* the existing Query String entries? Use the `[QSA]` flag in the RewriteRule. If this is only for certain Query Strings, you could use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  pattern
```

to select whether to rewrite.